# System GMM yields invalid results while Difference GMM is correct

Tags: panel-data, stata, generalized-moments

While studying about GMMs I generated the following dataset to experiment with.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = []
for individual_id in range(40):
    lag_y = 0
    for time in range(10):
        x1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1)[0]
        eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1)[0]
        individual_effect = individual_id
        y = 0.3 * x1 + individual_effect + 0.1*lag_y + 0.01 * eps
        rows.append(
            {
                'x1': x1,
                'y': y,
                'individual_id': individual_id,
                'time': time
            }
        )
        lag_y = y

df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows)
df.to_csv("sample_dataset.csv")
```

The population model is $y_{i,t} = 0.1y_{i,t-1} + 0.3x_{i,t} + \alpha_i + \varepsilon_{i,t}$.

When I fit a difference GMM in stata using

```
import delimited "sample_dataset.csv"
xtset individual_id time
xtabond2 y x L1.y, gmm(L2.y, collapse) iv(x) robust noleveleq
```

I get reasonable estimates

```
Favoring space over speed. To switch, type or click on mata: mata set matafavor speed, perm.
Warning: Two-step estimated covariance matrix of moments is singular.
  Using a generalized inverse to calculate robust weighting matrix for Hansen test.
  Difference-in-Sargan/Hansen statistics may be negative.

Dynamic panel-data estimation, one-step difference GMM
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group variable: individual~d                    Number of obs      =       320
Time variable : time                            Number of groups   =        40
Number of instruments = 8                       Obs per group: min =         8
Wald chi2(0)  =         .                                      avg =      8.00
Prob > chi2   =         .                                      max =         8
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   .2987912   .0008267   361.42   0.000     .2971709    .3004116
             |
           y |
         L1. |   .0987338   .0044346    22.26   0.000     .0900421    .1074255
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instruments for first differences equation
  Standard
    D.x
  GMM-type (missing=0, separate instruments for each period unless collapsed)
    L(1/9).L2.y collapsed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arellano-Bond test for AR(1) in first differences: z =  -4.52  Pr > z =  0.000
Arellano-Bond test for AR(2) in first differences: z =  -2.29  Pr > z =  0.022
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sargan test of overid. restrictions: chi2(6)    =   7.09  Prob > chi2 =  0.313
  (Not robust, but not weakened by many instruments.)
Hansen test of overid. restrictions: chi2(6)    =   8.32  Prob > chi2 =  0.215
  (Robust, but weakened by many instruments.)

Difference-in-Hansen tests of exogeneity of instrument subsets:
  iv(x)
    Hansen test excluding group:     chi2(5)    =   4.64  Prob > chi2 =  0.461
    Difference (null H = exogenous): chi2(1)    =   3.68  Prob > chi2 =  0.055
```

However, when running System GMM, the results are completely different and don't make sense with respect to the population model

```
. xtabond2 y x L1.y, gmm(L2.y, collapse) iv(x) robust
Favoring space over speed. To switch, type or click on mata: mata set matafavor speed, perm.
Warning: Two-step estimated covariance matrix of moments is singular.
  Using a generalized inverse to calculate robust weighting matrix for Hansen test.
  Difference-in-Sargan/Hansen statistics may be negative.

Dynamic panel-data estimation, one-step system GMM
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Group variable: individual~d                    Number of obs      =       360
Time variable : time                            Number of groups   =        40
Number of instruments = 10                      Obs per group: min =         9
Wald chi2(2)  = 207983.51                                      avg =      9.00
Prob > chi2   =     0.000                                      max =         9
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   .2817627   .0351817     8.01   0.000     .2128079    .3507175
             |
           y |
         L1. |   .9696906   .0080149   120.99   0.000     .9539817    .9853994
             |
       _cons |   .8759827    .238385     3.67   0.000     .4087566    1.343209
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instruments for first differences equation
  Standard
    D.x
  GMM-type (missing=0, separate instruments for each period unless collapsed)
    L(1/9).L2.y collapsed
Instruments for levels equation
  Standard
    x
    _cons
  GMM-type (missing=0, separate instruments for each period unless collapsed)
    D.L2.y collapsed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Arellano-Bond test for AR(1) in first differences: z =   0.87  Pr > z =  0.386
Arellano-Bond test for AR(2) in first differences: z =   0.76  Pr > z =  0.449
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sargan test of overid. restrictions: chi2(7)    =  15.21  Prob > chi2 =  0.033
  (Not robust, but not weakened by many instruments.)
Hansen test of overid. restrictions: chi2(7)    =  17.62  Prob > chi2 =  0.014
  (Robust, but weakened by many instruments.)

Difference-in-Hansen tests of exogeneity of instrument subsets:
  GMM instruments for levels
    Hansen test excluding group:     chi2(6)    =   8.70  Prob > chi2 =  0.191
    Difference (null H = exogenous): chi2(1)    =   8.91  Prob > chi2 =  0.003
  iv(x)
    Hansen test excluding group:     chi2(6)    =  16.99  Prob > chi2 =  0.009
    Difference (null H = exogenous): chi2(1)    =   0.62  Prob > chi2 =  0.430
```

A basic FE regression is much better even though there should be dynamic panel bias present.

```
. xtreg y x L1.y, fe vce(cluster individual)

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs      =       360
Group variable: individual~d                    Number of groups   =        40

R-sq:  within  = 0.9990                         Obs per group: min =         9
       between = 0.9940                                        avg =       9.0
       overall = 0.9475                                        max =         9

                                                F(2,39)            = 155735.95
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.9674                         Prob > F           =    0.0000

                         (Std. Err. adjusted for 40 clusters in individual_id)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           x |   .2995587   .0006096   491.40   0.000     .2983257    .3007918
             |
           y |
         L1. |   .0987098   .0005703   173.10   0.000     .0975564    .0998632
             |
       _cons |   19.52823   .0122089  1599.51   0.000     19.50353    19.55292
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  11.706987
     sigma_e |  .00997811
         rho |  .99999927   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Which assumption am I violating? Or what else I am doing wrong?

Why is there `_const` present for the system GMM?